# How to add an AudioSource based class to a MixerAudioSource

Tags: c++, audio, vst, juce

I’ve created a class for managing the audio of my synth:

```
class midiSource : public juce::AudioSource
```

I would like to add it to my mixer. However, the `MixerAudioSource` class accepts only AudioSource as input. How can I pass midiSource as an input source to my mixer?
(e.g.: `mixer.addInputSource(mySource, false);`)

Answer (score 0):

Since `juce::MixerAudioSource::addInputSource()` expects a pointer to a `juce::AudioSource`, or a subclass of `juce::AudioSource`, you can just pass `&mySource` to `addInputSource()`.